# How can I determine which video cards will fit into this computer?

Tags: graphics-card, case

Trying to purchase a video card with dual monitor support for my HP Elitedesk 800 desktop computer.

The specs say it is a 'small form factor.'  However, my research tells me this could mean one of many computer case sizes.  (Mini ATX, Micro ATX... I don't know!)

I did an amazon.com search and found some that are 4 inches wide, and some that are 1.5 inches wide.  I even found some that call themselves "SFF", but amazon is probably listing the dimension of the shipping box (7 inches).

How can I be sure the card will fit my desktop?  The case dimensions are 15x13.5x4" and it looks like the mounting bracket size for PCI slots is 3.125" wide.

Comment: If you know the case dimensions then you can determine if the card will fit inside the case.  Given you have a OEM case you should stay away from the high-performance cards that require more then a single slot.  The physical dimensions of the card are almost always provided on the product website by the manufacture.

Comment: Any half-height "Low profile" card will work. MiniATX, MicroATX, SFF, etc. is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [specs](http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/products/desktops/product-detail.html?oid=5387475#!tab=specs) on HP's support page:

```
Expansion slots:
2 *low-profile* PCIe x1
1 *low-profile* PCIe x16 (x4)
1 *low-profile* PCIe x16
```

That, plus looking at the rear:

[image]

Shows that they are standard "[low profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#Low-profile_cards)" slots, so practically any video card that is "low profile" should fit in the chassis.

Also on the support page under [Accessories and Services](http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/products/desktops/product-detail.html?oid=5387475#!tab=oas), you can pick "Graphics Cards" and get several examples of cards that will fit in:

[image]

Having said all that, your best bet (if possible) is to take the computer to the place you intend to buy the card from and try it before you buy it. :)